# Change a four digit number to a year in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a dataset that I'm working on. The dataset has a column with four-digit numbers. (1960, 1961,...2010)

I'm experimenting with the dataset in Power Query and I noticed that Power Query doesn't recognize the column as a year. Whenever I click on the column header and change the format to date, the numbers all change to 1905.

So, I tried to open it in Excel and change the formatting in it.

[a screenshot from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJKYu.png)

First, I tried to change the format to a yyyy date but the numbers turn to 1905.

I thought that maybe excel recognize the content of the columns as text so I tried to convert the text to a value in two ways (through the value() function and through multiplying the numbers by 1 then copying and pasting them as values) but whenever I change the format to a yyyy all the numbers change to 1905.

I tried the Text(,"YYYY") and it didn't work.

I tried to add a 01-01 to the column cells but it didn't work.

How can I let Excel or Power Query know that this column has years in it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: They're not actually years. They're integer values that you're choosing to interpret as years. Why do you think you need to convert them at all? They sort fine as integers (in chronological order), and you can label the column when displaying it to anything you want, including 'Year'.

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores dates as serial numbers with `1=1-Jan-1900`  So if you convert a number like 2000 to a date, Excel will add that number of days to `1-Jan-1900` and display the appropriate date.  There is no way for Excel to know that you expect the Integer 2000 to be translated to a year.

In Excel, to translate that to a year, you can use a formula in an adjacent column `=DATE(A1,1,1)` => `1-Jan-2000`

In PQ, you can also add a custom column with the formula `=#date([year],1,1)` where `year` is the name of your column with the year numbers, and the `year` column has `Int64.Type` or `whole number`